# SharePoint list column names not as created?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I created a list in office 365 and getting list items with REST.

Column names of list is "Baslik,Icerik,Tarih" but in response they seem; "Title,c53y,x4vu"(these are key of values, as you know resposne data in json format)

Why these keys differs from origin column names of list(as seem picture below)? and how can I edit it?

[image]

Comment: can you check internal name for this columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because I created these columns in list interface instead of creating in site columns panel. When create column with this name u specify only display name, internal name has set random values by SP. This [link](http://random%20values) explain the system clear.